# How to prevent labelText to break into 2 lines in TextField?

Tags: flutter, dart, label, textfield

I get that when text gets too long, the line needs to break but in my example there is still plenty of space to stay in one line. How do I do that?

[image]

-------EDIT------------

I just figured that the text breaks not because it doesn't have enough space above but because it doesn't have enough space in the field:

[image]

With that being said, I still don't know how to prevent breaking the line above. I guess not possible? The only way is to make sure the line doesn't break in the field and then it won't break above, either?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** This may not be a good workaround as it might lead to a bad User experience.

Inside the `TextField`s  `decoration: InputDecoration(` there is a `labelStyle` property. This can be used to effectively change the `fontSize` of `labelText` to make it fit on one line.

Example :

```
TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Enter your username or some long labeltext', labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 8) ),
    );
```

But as a suggestion, if the `labelText` content is getting long it might be a better idea to re-frame it in shorter simpler words.
Hope this helps.